# Doom/Melodic Death Metal for electric guitar

Tags: guitar, key, beginner, metal, genre

My friend and I are looking to just enjoy ourselves and record a Death Metal EP with some Doom and  Melodic Death Metal influences. With the tempo changes I know it sounds ridiculous but at this point it's hard to get my sounds out with words so I hope someone understands that.

Anyway, I know I'm going to play in drop C more than likely, I was just wondering what kind of theory lessons or small facts about how melodic death metal is composed would help me when I can hear it but I don't know how to fret it because it's complex to me.

I know the tempo of the songs are going to be frequently changing (which we want) and I'm not so worried about technique rather than finding some sort of key to play in (and I feel as if I know the answer is that it is up to me), and I know that string skipping and the 'audio illusion' of one sound has to be tonally correct. I am just sort of lost as to where to start building these improvised songs into something sensical.

Answer (score 2):

Try listening to some melodic death metal bands (In Flames as a starting point) then compare that with doom metal and see what the defining characteristics are.

After this, try to blend the two in a meaningful way. If you have a melodic lead line, attach it to a slow, plodding drum beat with simple chord variations underneath but keep the death metal growling vocals (for example).

There are many ways to do this, and of course what works is good.

Another way to do it would be a faster tempo, but with long ringing dissonant chords and cleanly sung vocals, with fast leads or solos.

And don't forget to downtune all the way to at least C ;)